# Are details logged anywhere on a go-around?

Tags: incidents, go-around

On March 1 I was a passenger on an American Airlines flight (AA 2315) landing at Denver International Airport, during the landing the pilot accelerated unexpectedly and started a turn.  He came on the intercom and explained that a Southwest flight had gotten too close, and so they decided to loop around and try the landing again.

Everything was fine, but I'm just so curious - are details about this incident logged anywhere?  I'd love to know more!

EDIT

There is a [great post](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/38830/is-an-aborted-landing-considered-an-incident-for-the-faa) that talks about all the different factors that go into determining whether an aborted landing is considered an "incident" or not.  Unfortunately, I don't know enough about the details to be able to determine whether my particular experience is an incident.  I'm hoping that incidents are publicly posted and I can search there to find out if my landing shows up or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is an aborted landing considered an incident for the FAA?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/38830/is-an-aborted-landing-considered-an-incident-for-the-faa) - specifically [my answer there](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/84302)

Comment: Great information!  Unfortunately, as I was in the middle seat on the exit row (so no window) I don't know a lot of the details (like how far off the ground we were).  Is there an online database that I can look at to see if it was reported (which seems unlikely)?

Comment: I looked it up on the history replay function of FR24.com. Your flight was co-altitude with a Southwest 737-700 that was turning onto approach to a parallel runway, at less than 1NM on a converging course. In my book, that qualifies a serious incident.

Comment: The most annoying part of all stack overflow sites, is the overzealous admins.  My post is NOT the same as these other posts - I'm not asking a general question, I'm asking a specific question about a specific incident.  DeltaLima actually answered the question, at least got started in the right direction (thank you!)

Comment: @DeltaLima - I can find my flight on fr24.com, but can't figure out how to find that Southwest 737-700.  How do you look at two flights at once?  And do you remember the flight # of the Southwest plane?  Thanks!

Comment: @DeltaLima - maybe serious, maybe not. Runways 16L/R are only 2600' apart so when they run simultaneous parallel arrivals (as they're [doing right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx6A1.png)) the aircraft *will* get closer than a mile, at the same altitude. But there are specific procedures that have to be followed, which I'll not go into the details of because I don't have any sort of familiarity with them. It's very possible that this could be a "serious" incident and it's also possible that SWA just drifted a little too close. I don't know which it is, but just saying.

Comment: @BettyCrokker Just so you are aware, and think poorly of our actual moderators (they have diamonds after their usernames), the 5 people who voted to close your question as a duplicate were regular users, albeit with high reputations, or high enough to be able to do so. Stack Exchange is a community curated question and answer site. A diamond mod _could_ close it, but they generally leave the "easy stuff" to us community members to do.

Comment: @CGCampbell Thanks for the clarification.  I amend my previous post to "The most annoying thing with all stack overflow sites are the users who overzealously close questions" :-)